# Postfix/Rancid - Confused by terminology, /etc/aliases, and relaying mail from localhost

Tags: email, postfix

I want to send notifications from a non-domain linux server, to my corporate email, `me@company.com`. My main concern is receiving notifications from an installed instance of rancid. I am confused by the postfix settings, e.g. `myorigin, mydomain, relay_domains...`, and how they relate to virtual domains, real external email addresses, and/or address classes. And if any of this is even relevant to what I need.

We have several linux servers within our corporate LAN. None of them are joined to the domain. All are in DNS. All can resolve company server names, and I can ssh/xrdp to all of them. They all have an instance of postfix, and I can manually send email, via telnet, to my exchange address `me@company.com`. Our exchange server allows anonymous authentication.

My rancid application runs, and pulls configuration files without issue. If I make changes to a device configuration, rancid recognizes this, and attempts to send an email to what is in `/etc/aliases`. This is where everything falls apart.

Postfix is installed on the same server that is running rancid. It is setup as a smarthost with Internet. I am unsure what needs to go in `mydestination, myorigin, mydomain`. Since this server is not joined to the AD domain, does the postfix `mydomain` value need to be `company.com` or `myhostanme`? Right now, notifications to `rancid-routers` go to `rancid-routers@company.com`, but there is no such user in our AD environment. I want those notifications to go to `me@company.com`. Here is a snippet from my `/etc/aliases`:

```
rancid-admin-routers: rancid-routers    # also tried me@company.com here
rancid-routers: rancid    # and here
rancid: me@company.com
```

I have changed almost every value in /etc/postfix/main.cf, that I imagine I screwed it up. So I removed postfix, and re-installed. This did not help.
How do I configure Postfix, and my `/etc/aliases` to forward all local mail to my exchange account? [relevant configs/error logs - pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GPYTE37i)

Comment: can postfix server on `IS-D-069` machine deliver mail directly to your corporate mail server that is handling mail for `company.com` or will it need a smarthost?

Comment: @clement I don't know enough about mail to answer that. If I `telnet localhost 25` while on `IS-D-069`, I can send an email to `me@company.com`. Not sure if this answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

it was looking like rancid change settings to make a single shipment notification email every 24 hours. I use RANCID for all my network device config backups. For non critical networks, or execs that wanted to know what was going on it the network .
Greetings and thank you